# Who stole the heroin in No Country For Old Men?

Tags: plot-explanation, no-country-for-old-men

The the last time we see the heroin in No Country for Old Men, Lewellyn Moss is present. He finds they money and heroin, but takes only takes the money.

The next time we are at the scene, Anton Chigur kills the two men and pursues the money. The heroin is not shown or discussed. Did Chigur get the heroin?

The next time we are at the scene, the heroin is gone, and Ed Tom Bell knows the heroin was there, but is now gone.

Did Moss or Chigur take the heroin? Was it someone else who came and took it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having read the book, I was under the impression it was the Mexicans who took the heroin, that is, the same guys who chase Moss after he returns to the cars in the night.

When Moss first finds the cars and the drugs, it is clear that he doesn't take the heroin with him: "He wet his forefinger and dipped it in the powder and smelled it. Then he wiped his finger on his jeans and pulled the tarp back over the parcels and stepped back and looked over the country again." When he returns to the cars the next night: "He shone the hooded light into the cargo space behind the seats. Everything gone."

Chigurh visits the scene only after all this has taken place, so the heroin was already gone by then.

It's been a while since I saw the film, so unfortunately I don't remember if the storyline differs from the book. Hope this helps anyway!

Comment: Okay, we don't actually see (in the movie) the Mexicans who chased Moss into the water take the herion. It's also never stated (in the movie or the book) who took it, right?

Answer (score 3):

The mexicans driving the pick up truck shooting the buck shot at Moss. They quickly cut his tires and went after him for the missing money. They didn't want to kill Moss so he'd be able to tell them where the money is. Poor Moss was providing a generous humanitarian effort to the mexican who asked him the previous evening for agua. These were the same men, the Mexicans at the motel room who were assassinated by Chigurh. The heroin was in the pick up at the motel. Useless to Chigurh. The Mexicans could sell it. The fat boss told Carson both were out of their product because the police investigating the crime scene at the motel would have confiscated the heroin from the pick up. Moss noticed the truck earlier that night and gave a 100 dollar bill to the taxi driver to take him to another motel.